# How to work with folders in python-jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, directory

I am trying simply to `list all jobs under a folder` (not view) with the **python-jenkins** package.

I have a structure, say, `https://jenkins.xxx.com/job/lvl1/job/lvl2/job/lvl3/`..

1. how can I **create a new folder** at a **specific location**, e.g. parallel to `lvl2`?
2. how can I **list all jobs under a specific folder**, say `lvl3`?

**How the folder entity is presented in the python-jenkins package**?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation regarding Folders](https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html?highlight=folder#example-8-working-with-jenkins-cloudbees-folders) ('cos that's what's job is inside: `job/<folder>/job`)

Comment: @Ian, how you navigate the hierarchic structure in my example? the create_job has two parameters: `create_job(name, config_xml)`, I can't see where the job be placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is to separate the jobs with a slash. So, if the path in Jenkins is: `parent/job/child1/job/child2`, you would use `server.get_job_info('parent/child1/child2')` and the library will convert this to the proper path.